# How to combine AJAX with JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I'm trying to read all information from the JSON string. I'm also trying to read it with the help of AJAX. The purpose is to fill an `innerHTML` with the information, but nothing works.

What is wrong with the code and how can it be solved?

```
function getResults() {

    var obj = [
      { "number": "Bob", "position": "forward", "shoots": "left" },
      { "number": "John", "position": "forward", "shoots": "right"  }
    ];


    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            var return_data = request.responseText;
            document.getElementById("sportresults").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", obj, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: starting from the beginning: do you get any errors in console? do you send a GET request to a URL? do you even get a response?

Comment: Are you trying to send JSON to a server or receive it from a server? If you're just wanting to show `obj` as JSON inside an element, Ajax isn't necessary for that.

Comment: Three questions, only one answered... you are not getting a response because maybe you are not sending a request? - do you get an errors in console? (i.e. using developer tools in your browser)

Comment: similar question: [How to make an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery) also see MDN [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX)

Answer (score 2):

Let's break down a few things you might be confused about

First, I think you have AJAX and JSON mixed up. AJAX (Asynchronous Javascript and XML) makes a JavaScript call asynchronously, while JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a data format.

In your instance, you can't make a call to get the object `obj` within your own code. You already have access to it, just use the variable `obj` for your needs.

Just write this,

```
document.getElementById("sportresults").innerHTML = obj;
```

If you do need to make a request get JSON, the `obj` value can be in it's own file or path and you can put it in `obj.json`.

Assuming that you have a file called `obj.json` that looks like this

```
[
  { "number": "Bob", "position": "forward", "shoots": "left" },
  { "number": "John", "position": "forward", "shoots": "right"  }
]
```

You can then call your code like this

```
function getResults() {

 var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        var return_data = request.responseText;
        document.getElementById("sportresults").innerHTML = return_data;
    }
 };
 xhttp.open("GET", 'obj.json', true);
 xhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should write your JSON into file, give path of the file to open function

Syntax of Open is
**void open(
   DOMString method,
   DOMString url,
   optional boolean async,
   optional DOMString user,
   optional DOMString password
);**

Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest